# ItemSource/DataSource for TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, dapper

I'm using dapper to retrieve some data from a database using a list. I've been able to do it with a ListBox using

```
private void UpdateBinding()
{
    displayLastNameLB.ItemsSource = people;
    displayLastNameLB.DisplayMemberPath = "FullInfo";
}
```

and now I want to display it inside a TextBlock but I can't find how. What would be the text block equivalent of `ItemSource` and `DisplayMemberPath`?
Here is the full code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UpdateBinding();
    }

    private void UpdateBinding()
    {
        displayLastNameLB.ItemsSource = people;
        displayLastNameLB.DisplayMemberPath = "FullInfo";
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        people = db.GetPeople(lastNameTB.Text);

        UpdateBinding();
    }
}
```

**The Person List**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string FullInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ FirstName } { LastName } ({ PhoneNumber })";
        }
    }

    public string FirstNameOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ FirstName }";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TextBox is intended to display information about single object in most cases, so there is no `ItemSource` and `DisplayMemberPath` You can create an additional property for storing a selected item and display is `FullInfo` Or create your own `ItemsControl` for that

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: You can `@` people so they can see your requests.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you are trying to ask here. A "*text block equivalent of ItemSource and DisplayMemberPath*" makes no sense at all. Are you perhaps asking how to declare an ItemTemplate with a TextBlock instead of using DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: Add your XAML file for clarity. Like @PavelAnikhouski mentioned you have List<People> so you need to bind to control where List,DataGrid. You could define a template in Listbox and bind Peoples to it

Comment: @Draxalot2: What exactly do you want to display in a `TextBlock`? Is it a single `TextBlock`or several?

Comment: Sorry, I want to display a single piece of data ie First Name in a textblock, so I believe I shouldn't use a list?

Comment: The list has multiple items (or none at all).  How do you intend to choose (or let the user chose) which item to show in the textblock?

Comment: I'm guessing a type that can only display single items. A string maybe?

Comment: @mm8 I would like to display it as a single textblock

Comment: @Draxalot2: Replace the `ListBox` with a `TextBlock` in the XAML and set the `Text` property?: `textBlock.Text = people[0].FullInfo; `

Comment: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'  
"  
It throws this exception @mm8

Comment: @Draxalot2: This  means that there are no `Person` objects in `people`. Do you see any data data in the `ListBox`? What does `db.GetPeople` actually return?

Comment: ```public List<Person> GetPeople(string lastName)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionValue("SampleDB")))
            {
              return connection.Query<Person>($"SELECT * FROM People WHERE LastName = '{ lastName }'").ToList();
            }
        }```     

This is the class that contains GetPeople. And yes data appears in the `ListBox` when I enter the correct `lastName.Text` @mm8

Comment: @Draxalot2: If it appears in the `ListBox`, it will also appear in the `TextBox` if you enter the same name. You are obviously doing something wrong. Please post your current code.

Comment: @mm8 The exception happens as soon as I run the project, so I dont even get a chance to enter in the `lastName`

Comment: @Draxalot2: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `ListBox` with a `TextBlock` in the XAML and set the `Text` property:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UpdateBinding();
    }

    private void UpdateBinding()
    {
        if (people != null && people.Count > 0)
        {
            textBlock.Text = people[0].FullInfo;
        }
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        people = db.GetPeople(lastNameTB.Text);
        UpdateBinding();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks!
If it's not too much to ask could you tell me how this particular code works? You dont have to answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF the preferred way to do this is to use DataBinding and models and view models that support [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged). In your example, I do not see an object in the `Window.DataContext`, so I am assuming it is just the Window itself. Here is a code example of how you could approach this:

```
// MainViewModel.cs
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        searchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchExecute);
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        protected set { Set(ref people, value); }
    }

    private string lastNameTB;
    public string LastNameTB
    {
        get { return lastNameTB; }
        set { Set(ref lastNameTB, value); }
    }

    private Person selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return selectedPerson; }
        set { Set(ref selectedPerson, value); }
    }

    private RelayCommand searchCommand;
    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get { return searchCommand; }
    }

    private void SearchExecute(object _)
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        var data = db.GetPeople(LastNameTB);
        var results = new ObservableCollection<Person>(data);
        People = results;
        SelectedPerson = results.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

// Person.cs
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { Set(ref firstName, value); FullInfo = null; }
    }

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { Set(ref lastName, value); FullInfo = null;  }
    }

    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { Set(ref email, value); }
    }

    private string phoneNumber;
    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return phoneNumber; }
        set { Set(ref phoneNumber, value); FullInfo = null;  }
    }

    private string fullInfo;
    public string FullInfo
    {
        get { return fullInfo; }
        set
        {
            value = $"{FirstName} {LastName} ({PhoneNumber})";
            Set(ref fullInfo, value);
        }
    }
}

// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="YourNameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Search"
        Height="400" Width="600"
        MinHeight="150" MinWidth="250">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vw:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Last Name</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="{Binding LastNameTB,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Last Name</Label>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding People,Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Phone Number" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="26" MinWidth="80" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">Search</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

// ObservableObject.cs (if you use an MVVM framework, there will most likely be a different base object)
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, bool doNotCheckEquality = false, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!doNotCheckEquality)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        }
        var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs<T>(propertyName);
        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName, args);
        return true;
    }
}

// RelayCommand.cs (just a simple version of RelayCommand; there are many different implementations)
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use a `ComboBox`. There you have a selected item and have a itemsource to let the user select from.

The `ComboBox` can look like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding people}" DisplayMemberPath="FullInfo" IsEditable="True"/>
```

With the `IsEditable="True"` the user can type in custom values and looks like a `TextBox`

Comment: No, I don't wanna use a ComboBox, I'd like to display a single line of data in a Textblock rather